# how to convert list of dates into Unix timestamps

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a list of dates that has unordered length and with day,mon,year pattern.and i want to return both ordered date and Unix timestamps.

what i have tried:

```
 from datetime import timezone
 import datetime

 data_lst = ['07 17', '01 2017', '05 2015', '2016', '7 04 1988']
 unix = []
 standard_date = []
 for i in data_lst:
    if i:
        data = i.split()
        if len(data) == 3:
            date = f'{data[0]}/{data[1]}/{data[2]}'
        if len(data) == 2:
            date = f'01/{data[0]}/{data[1]}'
        if len(data) == 1:
            date = f'01/01/{data[0]}'
        standard_date.append(date)
        d_m_y = date.split('/')
        if len(d_m_y[2]) == 2:
            d_m_y[2] = '20' + d_m_y[2]
        date = datetime.datetime  # i stuck here
```

what i got so far,

```
 print(standard_date)
 >>> ['01/07/17', '01/01/2017', '01/05/2015', '01/01/2016', '7/04/1988']
```

but my expected result:

```
 print(standard_date)
 print(unix)
 >>> ['01/07/17', '01/01/2017', '01/05/2015', '01/01/2016', '7/04/1988']
 >>> ['1498867....', '148322...', 'unix timestamp(01/05/2015)',and so on]
```

i got stuck in line 20.

Comment: You want to turn your dates into *UNIX timestamps*? One thing you'll need to clarify then: UNIX timestamps are accurate to the second, however you have a resolution of *a day* at best. What *time* should you assume for those dates to turn them into a UNIX timestamp? Midnight? Does it make sense at all to turn *dates* into *UNIX timestamps*?

Comment: @deceze yes, i want to turn dates into UNIX timestamps. time can be random and midnight time is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
dates = ['07 17', '01 2017', '05 2015', '2016', '7 04 1988']
unix_list = []
def try_parsing_date(text):
    for fmt in ('%m %y', '%m %Y', '%Y', '%y', '%d %m %y', '%d %m %Y'):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, fmt)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError('no valid date format found')


for date in dates:
    date = try_parsing_date(date)
    london_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
    date = london_tz.localize(date)
    utc_dt = date.astimezone(tz=pytz.utc)
    date_unix_tuple_list.append((date.strftime("%d/%m/%y"), int(utc_dt.timestamp())))
    date_unix_tuple_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) # this line sorts the dates 
standard_date = list(map(lambda x: x[0], date_unix_tuple_list))
utc = list(map(lambda x: x[1], date_unix_tuple_list))
print(standard_date)
print(utc)
```

This will output

```
['07/04/88', '01/05/15', '01/01/16', '01/01/17', '01/07/17']
[576374460, 1430438460, 1451606460, 1483228860, 1498867260]
```

You will also need to change 'Europe/London' to your timezone
To reverse the list, change the sorting line to

```
  date_unix_tuple_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```